# Spigot server hosted on website

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-spigot

I was wondering if it's possible to host a Minecraft Spigot server on a website?

Comment: Do you mean like host it embedded in the webpage and playable? otherwise you have to host it online anyway don't you? It is unclear what you're asking with this question

Comment: @PausePause Basically I was wondering if you can host it on a website to have a online server, without having to pay extra money to someone to host it for you.... instead of putting it on a domain you already own...... (also.... how does hosting a mc server even work.... I know how to set one up locally...... but I want it to be online) (does that make sense?)

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely possible to host a Spigot server on any server that you have full access to, but not on any public "web hosting" service.

If you have a "server" on which you can run and download applications, you can just download the latest server jar [here](https://launcher.mojang.com/v1/objects/3dc3d84a581f14691199cf6831b71ed1296a9fdf/server.jar), and start it with the following command:
`java -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui`

You can omit the `nogui` part if you want to see a visual representation of your CPU usage.

For plugins, you can put the zip files into the plugins folder (same as local).

After you start the server, it will be accesible from both the default IP address of the machine (if you have multiple), and all domains that are connected to this IP.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to have to make some assumptions based off information provided.

No. You cannot embed Minecraft to play on a webpage. You'll need the game client to run it.

If you want to host the Minecraft server so it's available from locations that aren't your home computer you'll be far better off paying a hosting service for a server with few slots. Since you've indicated you want to play alone this should be cheap, likely less than $25 annually (~$2 a month).

Using an server hosting service would also allow you to whitelist players from the game and prohibit unauthorized players from joining. Even if you don't using a hosting service's ability to whitelist the odds of any other players guessing your server IP address is so low it's practically nonexistent. I wouldn't worry about that.